# How to find minimum paths between vertices i and j with at most S vertices between them

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, dynamic-programming, floyd-warshall

Here is my code to implement Floyd algorithm. How can I change this algorithm to solve this question: 
Find the minimum distances between vertices i and j with at most S vertices between them.

```
void Floyd_Warshal(int graph[MAX][MAX], int D[MAX][MAX], int P[MAX][MAX], int numberOfNodes){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfNodes ; i++)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < numberOfNodes ; j++){
            D[i][j] = graph[i][j];
            P[i][j] = -1;
        }
    for(int k = 0 ; k < numberOfNodes ; k++)
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfNodes ; i++)
            for(int j = 0 ; j < numberOfNodes ; j++)
                if(D[i][j] > D[i][k] + D[k][j]){
                    D[i][j] = D[i][k] + D[k][j];
                    P[i][j] = k;
                }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered starting with Bellman-Ford rather than Floyd-Warshall?

Comment: @templatetypedef The weights of the edges are positive

Answer (score 1):

[Bellman-Ford algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) (the slightly modified version that does not use found paths from current iteration) on every iteration `i` can find all shortest paths that use at most `i` edges. Floyd-Warshall algorithm is not an appropriate method of solving these type of problems.

You can modify [Dijksta's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) as well, but it needs to change the graph. Modified graph will contain `|V|*(S+1)` vertices (for every vertex and every possible path length). This [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/53226) has a detailed explanation of the graph construction.